# R. Compute product of value in row by permutated value of other column n times

Tags: r, dataframe, permute

I have a data frame like this (1000000 rows):

```
A    B    C
a    0.2  4 
b    0.8  7
c    1    8
d    0.2  1
e    0.6  9
```

I would like to multiply each value in B by a random number taken from C (permutation without replacement) producing a new value x for each row. Then I want to sum all x values obtaining a new row y. Repeat this n times. I don't need the xn columns in my data frame, just a vector with the yn values.

I would get something like this (2 iterations):

```
A    B    C    x1           x2        .... xn
a    0.2  4    0.2*1=0.2    0.2*4=0.8
b    0.8  7    0.8*8=6.4    0.8*9=0.72
c    1    8    1*7=7        1*1=1
d    0.2  1    0.2*9=1.8    0.2*7=1.4
e    0.6  9    0.6*4=2.4    0.6*8=4.8
y              17.8         8.72      .... yn
```

Comment: What have you tried? An example of expected output would help. What do you mean by "column-wise"? Wouldn't you have just a single new column of B * (permutation of C), whose sum would be one element of y?

Comment: Hi @JuliusVainora, I just edited my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `replicate` helps here:

```
n <- 10
(y <- with(df, replicate(sum(B * sample(C)), n = n)))
# [1] 16.4 16.4 18.0 17.8 14.2 14.2 18.0 20.4 15.2 19.8
```

If sampling with replacement were an option, it could be made faster by generating a single large matrix of values of `C` and then using `colSums`.

Comment: Thank you @Julius Vainora, unfortunately I need it without replacement.

Comment: @Lucas, right, in that case my answer is a natural solution. Hopefully it's fast enough as well.

Comment: Excellent ! Thanks Julius